# Applications of Comparison Theorem of Bishop-Gromov

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I would like to know where I can find bibliographic references with applications of comparison theorem of Bishop-Gromov!
Thanks Very Much!

Comment: Look at the page 229 for this article: http://library.msri.org/books/Book30/files/zhu.pdf